# sql query for finding the next id in a table in a particular category

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

i have a table like this..

```
 Categories table
    -------------------
    ID Cat_Name
    1   cat1
    2   cat2
    3   cat3

Stations table
------------------
ID Sta_Name Cat_ID
1   sta1     1
2   sta2     3
3   sta3     2
4   sta4     1
5   sta5     1
6   sta6     3
```

Now i need to i have the only the ID input as 1(i.e, first row first col val) so now i want the output 4

since the next item in that category is 4

Next item in the sense i got the 1,4,6,9 id's in category 1 so now i have the input 6 now output must be 9 as the next item of 6 in category 1 is 9 if i gave input 9 the output must return 1

Comment: For MySQL or SQL-Server? Or both?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand a good method would be...

Considering just the "station table" and the current station ID

```
-- the one for next station
SELECT MIN(ID) as next FROM `stations` WHERE Cat_ID = {desidered_Cat_ID} AND ID > {your_current_ID} LIMIT 1;

-- the one for previous station
SELECT MAX(ID) as prev FROM `stations` WHERE Cat_ID = {desidered_Cat_ID} AND ID < {your_current_ID} LIMIT 1;
```

Hoping this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by *"next"*, how is order determined. At any rate, this is the basic approach:

```
select t2.ID
from MyTable t1
inner join MyTable t2 on t1.Cat_ID = t2.Cat_ID and t1.ID <> t2.ID
```

Comment: Next item in the sense i got the 1,4,6,9 id's in category 1 so 

now i have the input 6 now output must be 9 as the next item of 6 in category 1 is 9
if i gave input 9 the output must return 1

Answer (score 0):

```
select t2.id 
from mytable t1
inner join mytable t2 on t2.cat_id = t1.cat_id and t2.id > t1.id
limit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat unclear on as others too..  Is the 1 the ID you want to find the next ID by the same category as ID 1 (thus ID 4 is also same Cat_ID 1)?  I would try

```
select MIN( S2.ID ) as NextID
   from
      Stations S1
         JOIN Stations S2
            on S1.Cat_ID = S2.Cat_ID
           AND S2.ID > S1.ID
   where
      S1.ID = IDYouAreInterestedIn
```

I've renamed the table and aliases to match your new table edits...  In this case, "S1" and "S2" are "aliases" to your "Stations" table.

The Join command is based on the same category between the tables, but in addition, only include records in the second instance that have an ID GREATER than the one you are starting with (in your case, you were looking for 1)..  You don't want to return 1 as your answer for the 1 record you are starting with.  You want the first number AFTER the one you are on.

So, from your latest sample...

```
Stations table
------------------
ID Sta_Name Cat_ID
1   sta1     1
2   sta2     3
3   sta3     2
4   sta4     1
5   sta5     1
6   sta6     3


IF you enter    The next ID would be
ID = 1            4   (both category 1)
ID = 2            6   (the next instance of category 3)
ID = 3            No record found... no other "2" category
ID = 4            5   (first ID after 4 but same "1" category)
ID = 6            No record since nothing after 6 in the list.
```

Comment: @siddhartha,  see revised answer with your revised content sample

Comment: i am not able to get the answer with the above query have you tried it.. it returned me null
and.. 
as in your example If ID = 6 it must return the ID 2 ...

Comment: @siddhartha,  Sorry, but I'm not understanding YOUR logic.  Even in your sample, you are referring to some ID of 9 that's not even showing.  Additionally, you then refer to what sounds like going back to the beginning of the list as in a circular rotation.  I would elaborate more with your example as I tried to show here in mine of how the linking goes from A-B-C-D respectively.